# Нормализовать строку с json форматом

Tags: json, строки, python-3.6

Вообщем получаю по json запросу вот такой код:

```
{
"response": {
"type": "chat",
"title": "/testpool",
"admin_id": 385914179,
"members_count": 5,
"id": 367,
"users": [{
"id": 385914179,
"first_name": "Михаил",
"last_name": "Гнида",
"sex": 2,
"invited_by": 385914179,
"type": "profile"
}, {
"id": 483485532,
"first_name": "Феликс",
"last_name": "Флоринский",
"sex": 2,
"invited_by": 385914179,
"type": "profile"
}, {
"id": 454347313,
"first_name": "София",
"last_name": "Рэй",
"sex": 1,
"invited_by": 326998943,
"type": "profile"
}, {
"id": 326998943,
"first_name": "Никита",
"last_name": "Миронов",
"sex": 2,
"invited_by": 385914179,
"type": "profile"
}, {
"id": 469141130,
"first_name": "Ayanami",
"last_name": "Miyako",
"sex": 1,
"invited_by": 385914179,
"type": "profile"
}],
"photo_50": "https://pp.userap...6jtpvTktw.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_100": "https://pp.userap...CGZTDFK5w.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_200": "https://pp.userap...y2LG1ZU0c.jpg?ava=1"
}
}
```

Но когда вывожу там тамбуляция ужасная как можно это все выровнить в столбик?[image: Изображение вывода строки]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На **python**:

```
logger.debug('результат: %s' % json.dumps(my_json, indent=4))
```

На **js**:

Еесли объект

```
const obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": {"d": 3}};
const result = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

Если строка

```
const str = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": {"d": 3}}';
const result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(str), null, 2);
```

Comment: Это точно python?

Comment: сори, думал тебе на js)

Comment: Вот тогда `print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))`

Comment: Заработало благодарю)